# Bootstrap 5: Carousel inside Card won't maintain the same size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is shown in this GIF:

https://gifyu.com/image/B5nC

I'm using Bootstrap 5 to have a carousel inside a card. Although the images are shown properly, the card resizes as the images change. I want to prevent that and have a constant size for all the images.

Here's the relevant code:

```
           <div class="col">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <div class="card-img-top w-100">
                        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide >
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="carousel-item active
                                    <img src="1.png" class="d-block w-100 " alt="..." >
                                </div> 
                                <div class="carousel-item active
                                    <img src="2.png" class="d-block w-100 " alt="..." >
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item active
                                    <img src="3.png" class="d-block w-100 " alt="..." >
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <Button stuff, not so important...>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">a title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some text.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        Some Text here.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For improve your question use code snippet  instead
of Showing the  results in a  gif !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'd want to do, is add a fixed height or width to the image.

Add some css to the `img` tag. With that you can adjust the height of the image and center the image.
Something like so:

```
.carousel img {
    height: 220px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
```

The `object-fit: cover;` makes it so that the image will fit and not being stretched out. With `object-position: center;` it centers the image of the view. In this case it centers image on the height of 220px.

Here's a working example: https://www.codeply.com/p/y86ZKljAZS